# Micropower voltage regulator with discrete components

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, solar-cell, jfet, energy-harvesting

**Overview**

I have an unregulated power source (photodiodes BPW34) from which I want to get a regulated voltage output 1V. My load consumes less than 10 microamps of current at 1 V.

**Constraints:**

1. I'm trying to make the whole system low power (microwatts) so that I can power it with only a small number of photodiodes.
2. My circuit also needs to be built using discrete active components (MOSFETs, JFETs).
3. Output error of less than 5%.

**Till now**

1. I have tried using a Zener diode for voltage regulation and it worked fine but consumed at least 2 mA of current.
2. I also read about bandgap references which can run in lower power than Zener but not sure how to build it with discrete components.
3. On DigiKey, I found LDOs which work in microamps of current. How do they work? How can I build a similar version?

Comment: Can you explain why your system must be built from discrete components? Are you saying that no integrated circuits, such as op amps, can be used?

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid using integrated circuits likes op-amps. Discrete components mostly for learning purposes.

Comment: What is the input voltage and what accuracy of 1V do you want to achieve ? Do you want shunt regulator or LDO that does not consume power at all?

Comment: Input voltage is about 2V and I can also vary the number of photodiodes to increase or decrease it. Shunt regular or LDO both works. Need error of less than 2%.

Comment: Deleted my answer : it won't hit 2%. Put the specs in the question not the comments please.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I would like to see your answer. I guess 2% error is very aggressive. Little more is also okay. I have now added error in question.

Comment: See if this search offers inspiration.  https://www.google.com/search?q=1v+micropower+shunt+regulator&tbm=isch

Answer (score 1):

A simple shunt regulator would be best, since your photodiodes produce a bit more current than you need, and you can control their voltage by absorbing excess current.

This is only approximate and won't provide perfect regulation, but it's simple. You will probably need to adjust R2 to hit exactly 1V under typical situations; even then I don't know if it'll meet 5% error across your desired range of lighting conditions. Some testing required.

4 diodes will (according to the datasheet) produce 1.4V open circuit and up to 70uA into a short circuit.

Q1 is any low power NPN transistor with a reasonably high current gain (400) like a BC547C or BC847C (C grade is the high gain grade).

As the voltage builds up to close to 1, the transistor will start to turn on : at the microamp level, this happens well below the crude "0.6V" or "0.7V" approximate value, and 0.2 uA base current should be enough to absorb all the excess current produced by the photodiodes.

A MOSFET with a threshold voltage around 0.5V would also work, but the variability between devices is likely to be much greater than Vbe with bipolar transistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faD4c9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>